# Make [quilljs] a synonym of [quill]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I suggest to make [quilljs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quilljs) a synonym of [quill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quill). The latter is more popular and has a wiki, while quilljs is [legacy name](https://www.npmjs.com/package/quilljs) of Quill 0.x.

Comment: If this were a burnination request we could \[[tag:quill]\] it with fire...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tag wiki for the [quilljs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quilljs) tag was a list of links to https://quilljs.com, which mentions that "Quill" is the current name. Also, 83 of the 122 questions in the [quilljs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quilljs) tag already had the [quill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quill) tag. So it is quite clear that a synonym is a good idea here.

I've added [quilljs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quilljs) as a synonym for [quill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quill), that is: 
[quill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quill) (× 563) ← [quilljs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quilljs) (× 122).